# How to override daisy ui styles?

Tags: tailwind-css, daisyui

I want to modify default stying in daisy UI.

I have used the following code
 `<button class="btn btn-primary bg-black">I am a button</button>`

[This is how the button look](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3xeNh.png)

But I want a black background for this.

In daisyui website have found the following:
[daisy UI website screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8hUCR.png)

And when I copy this code in my vs code:
[vs code screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R07OA.png)
I am getting:
[output screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WteZV.png)

I know that it is possible to use the daisy UI theme. But sometimes a little modification is required like ml-2 , p-4 etc.

Comment: Are you sure your tailwind css is in you stylesheets list ? Does it work when you try to apply other tailwind classes ?

Comment: are you using cdn? js or css

Comment: i have used cdn.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you include tailwind cdn as well:

```
<script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com"></script>
```

More info is available on this link:
https://reacthustle.com/blog/how-to-modify-daisyui-theme-using-cdn